# unexpected behavior of angularjs ng-pattern directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to validate text field using ng-pattern. The field should accept all characters but whitespace.

I wrote following html:

```
<input name="username" ng-model="username" ng-pattern='/^[\S]+$/' type="text">
```

When I evaluate

```
{{username.$valid}}
```

Starting and trailing whitespaces are ignored. It evaluates String "    d  " (without quote) as valid.

What is the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't remove space wrapper from input.

You can try to use `ng-trim='false'` ( > ver 1.1.1)

Other alternative way to prevent to user to enter empty spaces.

**HTML**

```
<input ng-model='name' ng-trim='false' />
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$timeout) {
 $scope.name = 'World';
 $scope.$watch('name', function() {
     $scope.name = $scope.name.replace(/\s+/g,'');
  });
});
```

see <kbd>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mb0uRyIIv1eK8nTg3Qng?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I think it is about your pattern try it as follows;

```
/^[\S]*$/
```